# for /f loop "tokens and delimiters" didn't work with variables (batch file)

Tags: variables, batch-file

recently I was making a batch file I ran into a problem,
when I made a for /f loop, I used a variable in "tokens", like this example:

```
for /f "delims= tokens=!count2!" %%a in ('type test.txt 2^>nul') do (
```

like you can see, i have the variable `!count2!`, in the loop.
and when i tested it, it displayed `!count2!" was unexpected at this time`. And I dont know why?

can anyone help?

here is the full code of what I have tried:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "count1=0"
set "count2=0"
for /l %%b in (1 1 10) do (
    set /a "count2+=1"
    set /a "count1+=1"
    for /f "delims= tokens=!count2!" %%a in ('type test.txt 2^>nul') do (
        set "str!count1!=%%a"
    )
)
echo !str1! !str2! !str3! !str4!
pause
```

by the way, test.txt contains `test hello # ###`

and, I want to set `test`, `hello`, `#` and `###` as their own variable (str1, str2, str3 and str4).

and yes I have tried to do it with % instead of !

tell me if i wasn't clear enough!

thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why bothering with tokens?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in (test.txt) do for %%j in (%%i) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set str!count!=%%j
)
set str
```